# When is it possible to extend several linear orders defined "locally" into a single linear order defined "globally"?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, order-theory, hypergraph, simplicial-complexes

This is a somewhat fuzzy question, so I will try my best to give a formulation which includes everything relevant while excluding everything else. I would like to find out if anyone else has studied problems similar to the following one (in all likelihood using different terminology). The formulation might be a bit clunky, and I apologise for that - part of the reason I am asking this here is precisely because I want to find out if there is another, perhaps more natural way of stating the question. This is my way of describing it:

Let $X$ be a finite set, and let $X_1, \dots, X_k$ be subsets of it covering $X$. Suppose that each $X_i$ is linearly ordered by "local orders" $\leq_i$, *in such a way that the appropriate orders agree on every intersection* (let us call this condition **local consistency**). One can then consider the union of the $\leq_i$ (interpreted as a digraph over $X$ that we call the **conflict graph**), and it is standard that there exists an order $\leq$ defined on the whole of $X$ which extends every $\leq_i$ if and only if the digraph described above is acyclic (use topological sorting). If this condition holds (that is, the conflict graph is acyclic), we call the system $((X_i, \leq_i))_{1 \leq i \leq k}$ **globally consistent**.

What I am looking for is characterisations for situations where the system is "not too far" from globally consistent. To make this a bit more precise, we allow an operation of "splitting" a local order $\leq_i$. I will not give a formal definition, but intuitively, elements from a downwards closed set in $X_i$ become $\leq_i$-incomparable with elements from its complement in $X_i$ (in other words, we delete an oriented complete bipartite subgraph from the conflict graph). It is clear that after a finite number of those operations, the system will be globally consistent (we may simply split the orders until no distinct elements are comparable). We call the smallest number of cuts required the **global inconsistency** of the system. In this language, the problem I am interested in is characterising systems of bounded global inconsistency.

Does anyone know of any work on this problem, or on problems similar to this one? I can imagine that something analogous might have been studied in the language of hypergraphs, set systems, relations or simplicial complexes (there is a notion of "ordered simplicial complex" out there, but it seems to deal with simplicial complexes that are already globally consistent). I couldn't find anything relevant, but I am not an expert in those fields, so I might not be searching for the correct keywords.

Comment: Not exactly what you want but there is a classic problem for obtaining an acyclic graph by removing small number of edges called [Feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set).

Comment: I suppose the problem can indeed be seen as a generalisation of the feedback arc set problem, where we are allowed to remove certain "thick arcs" instead of just arcs. This is good insight, thanks @MaxAlekseyev!